# Gradle: What is the difference between the tasks 'build' and 'buildSearchableOptions'?

Tags: gradle

I am building a plugin in IntelliJ and Gradle, and have the following question:

What is the difference between the predefined tasks `build` and `buildSearchableOptions` in Gradle?

I can see that `:buildSearchableOptions` is called as part of `:build` and that it produces its own JAR file.

Comment: This task is not a standard gradle task. Run `./gradlew tasks` and see what the description of the task is. Search which plugin it comes from, and read its documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much, I wasn't aware of that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They come from two different plugins.

Assuming a Java project, the `build` task comes from the `java` plugin which in turn comes from the life cycle/base plugin:

- https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/plugins/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/plugins/JavaBasePlugin.java#L74
- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/base_plugin.html

The `buildSearchableOptions` task comes from the `org.jetbrains.intellij` plugin:

- https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/org/jetbrains/intellij/IntelliJPlugin.groovy#L350..L360
- https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin#tasks